# Как достать определённую часть строки и поместить её в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть квадратное уравнение, заданное ввиде строки:

```
"ax^2+bx+c=0"
```

Как я могу рассчитать дискриминант этого уравнения, при том условии, что *a*, *b* и *c* могут быть любыми (одно-, двух-, трёх- и т.д... -значными) числами?

Пожалуйтса, покажите как можно достать ту часть строки, которая, например, находится между *+/-* и переменной *x* и записать её в переменную *b*?

Comment: «a, b и c могут быть любыми» — а могут отсутствовать? (0)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME даже не задумывался об этом. Думаю, что отсутствовать они не могут, но могут быть равны нулю, что, в принципе, ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

можно разделить строку по 'x'

```
equation = '-13x^2+42x+111=0'

members = equation.split('x')
['-13', '^2+42', '+111=0']
```

удалить лишнее

```
a = members[0]
b = members[1].replace('^2', '')
c = members[2].replace('=0', '')

>>> a, b, c
('-13', '+42', '+111')
```

и преобразовать к float (int)

```
>>> a, b, c = float(a), float(b), float(c)
>>> a, b, c
(-13.0, 42.0, 111.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно регуляркой вытащить. Результатом будет 3 строки, которые приведем к числам через `map` + `float`

*Для вещественных чисел в строке нужно будет усложнить регулярку, т.к. `\d` ищет только символы 0-9. Для этого `(-?\d+)` нужно заменить на `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`, тогда регулярка найдет и числа с точкой вида `123.456`*

Например:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(-?\d+)x\^2\+(-?\d+)x\+(-?\d+)=0")

m = pattern.search("123x^2+456x+789=0")
print(m.groups())
# ('123', '456', '789')

a, b, c = m.groups()
print(a, b, c)
# 123 456 789

a, b, c = map(float, m.groups())
print(a, b, c)
# 123.0 456.0 789.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь паттерн, который находит в строке знаки "+ и -"

```
pattern = re.compile(r"-|\+")
```

Далее помещаешь элементы, которые находятся между знаками "+-" в список с помощью генератора списков

```
ls = [i for i in pattern.split(str)]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]